# Catching numberformatException while parsing to Double

Tags: android, exception, number-formatting

I want to validate input set with some condition.
here i am getting `NumberFormatException` while pasring the number. I want to throw `InvalidInputException` if number which was entered in textbox contains anything except numbers. 
Now if I'm inputting numbers only then also I'm getting `NumberFormatException`.
Here is the sample code.
call to `validateInput` is as follows

```
 try {
                    if (true == validateInput(name.getText().toString(), number
                            .getText().toString())) {
                        // do something
                    }
                } catch (InvalidInputException iie) {
                    Log.d("@gaurav", "not a valid input" + iie);
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Invalid input set", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Problem while cerating contact", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
                    Log.d("@gaurav", "Problem while cerating contact", ex);
                } finally {
                 // do something    
                }
```

`ValidateInput()` is as follows:

```
 * Name is valid if it starts with an alphabet otherwise not valid Number is
 * valid if the entered text is integer only, 
 * if not valid number/name throws InvalidInputException, otherwise true
 * */
private boolean validateInput(String name, String number)
        throws InvalidInputException {
    InvalidInputException iie = new InvalidInputException();
    try {
        if (name.isEmpty() || number.isEmpty()) {
            Log.d("@gaurav.exception", "input field empty");
            iie.addDescription("Input field is empty");
            throw iie;
        } else {
            if (false == Character.isLetter(name.charAt(0))) {
                Log.d("@gaurav.exception", "first letter of name is not a letter");
                iie.addDescription("first letter of the name is not character");
                throw iie;
            }
            Log.d("@gaurav.exception", "checking number");
        Log.d("@gaurav.exception","number is :"+number+":");                  
            Double.parseDouble(number);
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        Log.d("@gaurav.exception", "In numberFormatexception, adding description, re-throwing iie");
        iie.addDescription("Number field should contain integer only");
        throw iie;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("@gaurav.exception", "Exception, re-throwing iie");
        throw iie;
    }
    iie = null;
    return true;
}
```

and `MyCustomException` is as follows

```
package com.gaurav.contactmanager.model;

public class InvalidInputException extends Exception {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5585822470459144546L;
    String description;

    public InvalidInputException() {
        super();
    }

    public InvalidInputException(String desc) {
        this.description = desc;
    }

    public void addDescription(String desc) {
        description = desc;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return description + "\n\n" + super.toString();
    }

}
```

Logcat shows something like this:

```
01-02 02:11:59.310: D/@gaurav.exception(408): checking number
01-02 02:11:59.321: D/@gaurav.exception(408): number is :６６６６:
01-02 02:11:59.330: D/@gaurav.exception(408): In numberFormatexception, adding description, re-throwing iie
01-02 02:11:59.330: D/@gaurav(408): not a valid inputNumber field should contain integer only
01-02 02:11:59.330: D/@gaurav(408): com.gaurav.contactmanager.model.InvalidInputException
```

Comment: Don't use `true == condition` and `false == condition`, use `condition` resp. `!condition` instead.

Comment: @martijno this is for my convinience as it improves the readablity for me, but i guess problem is with "Double.parseDouble(number)" as log suggests it is checking number and then caught in exception

Comment: From your stacktrace looks like the code works correctly, assuming that the passed number is not a valid Double. Could you include the problematic value into logs, preferably between [] as to be sure there are no spaces around. There is nothing in your code and logs to assume that this string variable contains the valid representation of the double.

Comment: sure i will check this scenario also, as this seems to be causing problem

Comment: @AudriusMeškauskas I added the Log and check the value that number is holding, for ensuring it is holding space or not i putted it inside semicolon. please see the revised log output and suggest where i am going wrong

Comment: `６６６６` is what kind of number? Sure you actually typed correctly? `6666` vs `６６６６` .... just wondering which kind of encoding are you using?

Comment: I am using nothing special, i am inputting number as provided by android keypad, neither i am changing any format. I am just inputting number with keypad, getting the number and passing it to my method. That's it. Even i was little confused with the font of this number

Comment: @AudriusMeškauskas i installed the apk on device, i found it is working fine on device, but i am curious to know whats wrong was with emulator and this was happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was some issue in the type/format of the number i was inputting and that was root cause of the problem. Trying to run the same code on other device confirms that it was input type/format issue.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to do

```
 Double.parseDouble(number);
```

Which won't work on any input except input which can be parsed to Double.

You might want to do something like

```
try{
     Double.parseDouble(number);
}catch(NumberFormatException e)
{
    throw iie;
}
```

Comment: Here Double.parseDouble(number); is already in try block, and it is catching exception also. I am inputting 999 as number in string format and getting this exception. I doubt this solution will work or not, but still i will give it a chance and let you know that is it ok